# How to change td color in jQuery on click and hold

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a grid to fill tds with color on a *click and hold*.

I have it to where a click fills a single cell, but now I am trying to get it to fill the cell on a click and hold as well.

I've tried using event listeners on `mouseup`, `mousedown`, and `mousehover`, but I can't seem to get the right combo to make it work. Any guidance?

```js
// Single page app to create a grid and fill it with color
// when clicked

// function to make canvas
function makeGrid(height, width) {
  for (i = 0; i < height; i++){
    $('#tableBody').prepend('<tr></tr>');
  }
  for (j = 0; j < width; j++){
      $('tr').append('<td></td>');
  }
}

$(':submit').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#tableBody').empty(); //empty out any existing grid
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevent resetting everything on click
  let height = $('#inputHeight').val(); //get height of canvas
  let width = $('#inputWeight').val(); // get width of canvas
  makeGrid(height, width); // Generate Canvas
}); 

// This code works to fill the td's with color on a click
$('#tableBody').on('click', 'td', function() {
  $(this).css('background', $('#colorPicker').val());
});

// I'm trying to get the color to fill if the mouse is down
// and has not been released, started with this code and
// tried a few other ways but can't get it to work

// var mousedown = false;

// $(document).mousedown( function () { mousedown = true;});
// $(document).mouseup( function() { mousedown = false; });

// $('td').on('mousedown', function() {
//   $(this).css('background', $('#colorPicker').val());
// });

// $('#tablebody td').on('mouseover', function() {
//   if (mousedown) {
//     $(this).css('background', $('#colorPicker').val());
//   }
// });
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Griffy', cursive;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
    font-weight: 100;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 6em;
}

div#selections {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Griffy" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>
    <div id='selections'>
        <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
        <form id="sizePicker">
            Grid Height:
            <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
            Grid Width:
            <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="1">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
        <input type="color" id="colorPicker">
    </div>

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas">
        <tbody id="tableBody">

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party links as those links can die over time. Just insert a "code snippet" right here in your question. Also, you should include enough of the relevant HTML and CSS as well so that we can have a running example of what you are working with and can provide you with a working answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus roger that, thanks for putting the CSS in there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `mousedown`/`mouseover`/`mouseup`/`mouseleave`  like below. `click` won't even be necessary anymore.

`mouseleave` is needed because `#tableBody` can't track `mouseup` if it leaves it. You can remove it if you hook a listener to `document`'s `mouseup` instead.

```js
// Single page app to create a grid and fill it with color
// when clicked

// function to make canvas
function makeGrid(height, width) {
  for (i = 0; i < height; i++){
    $('#tableBody').prepend('<tr></tr>');
  }
  for (j = 0; j < width; j++){
      $('tr').append('<td></td>');
  }
}

$(':submit').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#tableBody').empty(); //empty out any existing grid
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevent resetting everything on click
  let height = $('#inputHeight').val(); //get height of canvas
  let width = $('#inputWeight').val(); // get width of canvas
  makeGrid(height, width); // Generate Canvas
}); 

// This code works to fill the td's with color on a click
//$('#tableBody').on('click', 'td', function() {
//  $(this).css('background', $('#colorPicker').val());
//});

(function () {
  var isMouseDown = false;
  $('#tableBody')
    .on('mousedown', 'td', function() {
      isMouseDown = true;
      $(this).css('background', $('#colorPicker').val());
    })
    .on('mouseover', 'td', function() {
      if (isMouseDown)
      $(this).css('background', $('#colorPicker').val());
    })
    .on('mouseup', 'td', function() {
      isMouseDown = false;
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
      isMouseDown = false;
    });;
})();
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Griffy', cursive;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
    font-weight: 100;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 6em;
}

div#selections {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Griffy" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>
    <div id='selections'>
        <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
        <form id="sizePicker">
            Grid Height:
            <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="11">
            Grid Width:
            <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="11">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
        <input type="color" id="colorPicker">
    </div>

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas">
        <tbody id="tableBody">

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate it!  That worked perfectly!  I understand it now that I see it.  I'm new to front end dev. Can you explain why you have a "(" in front  of the function? Also, why is there an extra "()" at the end?

Comment: Ah, about the `(`: if I just declared `var isMouseDown = false;`, that variable would go to the global scope (`window.isMouseDown`, actually).  And then any code could execute it (which is unlikely, but, anyway, it would be putting uneeded vars in the global scope).

Comment: To prevent `isMouseDown` from going to the global scope, I declared a function, placed the whole code inside such function, and ran it right away.

Comment: I tried before and couldn't, but I can upvote it now that you told me, thanks!

Comment: So, the code is: `(function () { /* some code */})();` is the declaration of the function (without a name) and execution of it right away. It's the same as  `function myFunctionWithName() { /* some code */}; myFunctionWithName();`. See?

Comment: The term for that is IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE it is used to prevent polluting the global scope.

Comment: I see, so the beginning ( and () ending syntax creates a function and therefore keeps your variable local instead of global.  I learned a ton from this, thanks!

Comment: I get it, thanks so much for taking your time to do this, means a lot to a new dev! :)